# wp-login.php register/lost password links to buttons?

Tags: wp-login-form, wp-register-style

How do I style the wp-login.php register/lost password links to buttons for an easier mobile UI?

Where do I find the HTML to append the ahref to a submit? And which CSS file do style that button in?

No need to change the call-to-action, just the change a text link to a button!

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to change the output of the file because the there aren't any filters you can hook into.

However, there are some hooks that you can use like the `login_enqueue_scripts` hook to enqueue jQuery and/or a custom javascript. And then `login_footer` to print some jQuery that will add classes that you can then style with CSS.

```
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_login_enqueue_scripts' );
function wpse_login_enqueue_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'login_footer', 'wpse_login_footer' );
function wpse_login_footer() {
  print( '<script>jQuery("a[href$=register]").addClass("button");'
  . 'jQuery("a[href$=lostpassword]").addClass("button");</script>'
  . '<style>.login #nav a.button{color:#123456;}</style> );
}
```

This code would go either in your `functions.php` file or a separate plugin.